# Using RedLaser SDK via MonoTouch crashing as soon as BarcodePickerController shown

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm using Chris Branson's RedLaser MonoTouch bindings and sample from here:
https://github.com/chrisbranson/RedLaserSample

Firstly, to help out those also having trouble with this sample project, I had to update both the makefile to build the RedLaser.dll MonoTouch bindings and the sample MonoDevelop csproj to get the actual app compiling.

- **Makefile**
  The makefile supplied by Chris unzipped the RedLaser SDK download, but RedLaser changed their naming convention and so it was no longer working. I simplified it, instead requiring the user to put the libRedLaserSDK.a file into the build directory manually:

  ```
  BTOUCH=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch
  BUILDVER=build139
  VERSION=3.2.4
  BINDIR=./bin/

  all: $(BINDIR)RedLaser.dll

  $(BINDIR)libRedLaserSDK.a: 
      @echo "You'll need to obtain a copy of RedLaserDevSDK-$(VERSION).zip from"
      @echo "http://redlaser.com/sdk/index.php"
      @echo Locate the libRedLaserSDK.a file and place within
      @echo $(BINDIR)
      @echo 
      @open http://redlaser.com/sdk/index.php
      @exit 1

  $(BINDIR)RedLaser.dll: Makefile AssemblyInfo.cs RedLaser.cs enums.cs $(BINDIR)libRedLaserSDK.a
      $(BTOUCH) --out=$@ -e RedLaser.cs enums.cs AssemblyInfo.cs --link-with=$(BINDIR)libRedLaserSDK.a,libRedLaserSDK.a

  clean:
      -rm -rf $(BINDIR)*.dll
  ```

  The directory containing the makefile should also contain the files `redlaser.cs`, `enums.cs` and `AssemblyInfo.cs` (i.e. the same as Chris's).
- **MonoDevelop project build settings**
  I think the reason this stopped working was a bug in MonoDevelop or MonoTouch and the way it expands the 'Additional mtouch arguments' when they contained quotation marks. Chris's original arguments looked like this:

  ```
  -cxx -gcc_flags="-framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -L${ProjectDir}/Lib -lRedLaserSDK -ObjC"
  ```

  MonoDevelop doesn't parse this correctly, instead inserting quotation marks around each option separated by a space. Looking in the build output (under 'Compiling to native code') showed that this got expanded to:

  ```
  "/Users/tyson/Downloads/chrisbranson-RedLaserSample-1a5545f-1/RedLaserSample/Lib/RedLaser.dll" -debug -nolink -sdk "5.1" -targetver "5.1" --armv7 "-cxx" "-gcc_flags=\"-framework" "SystemConfiguration" "-framework" "CFNetwork" "-framework" "CoreVideo" "-framework" "CoreMedia" "-framework" "AVFoundation" "-framework" "OpenGLES" "-framework" "Security" "-L/Users/tyson/Downloads/chrisbranson-RedLaserSample-1a5545f-1/RedLaserSample/Lib" "-lRedLaserSDK" "-ObjC\""
  ```

  The solution involves adding explicit quotation marks around the whole 'gcc_flags' option, manually escaping the inner quotation marks. e.g:

  ```
  "-cxx" "-gcc_flags=\"-framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -L${ProjectDir}/Lib -lRedLaserSDK -ObjC\""
  ```

  This expands correctly into:

  ```
  "/Users/tyson/Downloads/chrisbranson-RedLaserSample-1a5545f-1/RedLaserSample/Lib/RedLaser.dll" -debug -nolink -sdk "5.1" -targetver "5.1" --armv7 "-cxx" "-gcc_flags=\"-framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -L/Users/tyson/Downloads/chrisbranson-RedLaserSample-1a5545f-1/RedLaserSample/Lib -lRedLaserSDK -ObjC\""
  ```

Ok, so now that I had it compiling I attempted to run it on my phone. The app loads up fine, and successfully calls into the RedLaser SDK via the `RedLaserSDK.CheckReadyStatus()` function. But as soon as I hit the scan button (which loads the `BarcodePickerController`) it crashes with a native exception deep within the RedLaser SDK:

```
terminate called throwing an exception
Native stacktrace:

0   RedLaserSample                      0x0159d62d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
1   RedLaserSample                      0x015b6251 sigabrt_signal_handler + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x319b67ed _sigtramp + 48
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x319ac20f pthread_kill + 54
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x319a529f abort + 94
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x34fb1f6b abort_message + 46
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x34faf34d _ZL17default_terminatev + 24
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x358e536f _objc_terminate + 170
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x34faf3c5 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x34faf451 _ZdlPv + 0
10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x34fb079f __cxa_throw + 122
11  RedLaserSample                      0x000404a9 _ZN5zxing6qrcode19FinderPatternFinder18selectBestPatternsEv + 172
12  RedLaserSample                      0x000415e9 _ZN5zxing6qrcode19FinderPatternFinder4findERKNS_11DecodeHintsE + 512
13  RedLaserSample                      0x0003a7f7 _ZN5zxing6qrcode8Detector6detectERKNS_11DecodeHintsE + 366
14  RedLaserSample                      0x00046b97 _ZN5zxing6qrcode12QRCodeReader6decodeENS_3RefINS_12BinaryBitmapEEENS_11DecodeHintsE + 130
15  RedLaserSample                      0x0004ec35 _ZN5zxing6Reader6decodeENS_3RefINS_12BinaryBitmapEEE + 240
16  RedLaserSample                      0x00058455 -[FormatReader decode:] + 116
17  RedLaserSample                      0x00013835 -[ZXingDecoder findCodesInBitmap:bytesPerRow:width:height:] + 656
18  RedLaserSample                      0x0005f6af -[BarcodePhotoEngine zxingFindBarcodesInPixmap:] + 222
19  RedLaserSample                      0x00055f25 __38-[BarcodeEngine findBarcodesInPixMap:]_block_invoke_059 + 76
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x34635c59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x34637d0f _dispatch_queue_drain + 274
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x34637b75 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x346387e7 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 210
24  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31967dfb _pthread_wqthread + 294
25  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31967cd0 start_wqthread + 8

=================================================================  
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates  
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  
used by your application.  
=================================================================
```

Running the very similar RedLaser Xcode sample project (i.e. no MonoTouch involvement, all objective-c) works fine.

Also, if it is of any significance, disabling all barcode scan types allows the `BarcodePickerController` to load up and display the camera view. Obviously it never detects a barcode though.

Comment: Just an idea, have you tried using a MonoTouch binding project instead of their makefile?  I have always had better luck compiling Objective-C bindings that way (and you can easily put it in source control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash you mention has been [fixed in the bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/commit/2deec96726c7125e73a8f09d80d2618745ad0dbf) now.

It was related to QR's usage of C++ exceptions and incorrect linking arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using ZBar now, but I was still very curious about what caused this. I looked up your commit and added a link to it in your above answer, just to see what the change was (and let others curious about it see it too).
So that `NeedsGccExceptionHandling` option you added, is that required for any binding to a library that can throw a c++ exception from a bound function call? Does it cause all function bindings to be wrapped in a try-catch and throw a CIL compatible exception?

Comment: @Tyson: actually it's the opposite: I'm setting `NeedsGccExceptionHandling` to false. This value will currently make MonoTouch pass -lgcc_eh to the linker, and this is the actual problem (we end up with some of the exception handling functions loaded twice in the binary, in particular the function which registers catch handlers - but not the function handling the throw statement. If the throw function doesn't match with the catch function, the throw function will not find any catch handlers and abort the process).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Makefile you pasted, this RedLaser binding uses the LinkWith[1] feature supported by MonoTouch to eliminate the need to use any "Additional mtouch arguments".

Just wipe out any arguments needed for RedLaser from your additional mtouch arguments configuration in your Project Options and things will likely build & work properly.

If not, try using the RedLaser binding from https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-bindings which may be more up-to-date?

Notes:

1. http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/11/02/monotouch-native-libraries-made-easy/

Comment: Haha 'may be more up-to-date' - From the github page: "RedLaser    39 minutes ago    [RedLaser] Added -unsafe to btouch args as it is now needed. [jstedfast]." Thanks, I'll check it out now.

Comment: Oh and removing all the 'additional mtouch arguments' doesn't work, I already tried that.

Comment: Ok, so I got the latest RedLaser.dll binding compiled using the makefile in the linked GitHub repo. No problems. I copied it into the root of the sample project that comes with it, checked the 'additional mtouch arguements' and confirmed they are no longer needed (it is empty). Everything compiled fine. Nice! Loaded onto my phone and ran - got to the first page where it showed the correct Eval version of RedLaserSDK, but again as soon as I hit scan I get the exact same SIGABRT crash as above. I'm switching to ZBar... I'll upload my bindings somewhere once I'm done.

Comment: After reading up on the new 'LinkWith' feature, I noticed that the libRedLaserSDK and all the dependent frameworks were linked, but nowhere did it specify the linked 'libiconv.dylib' that the RedLaser XCode sample project links. I followed the instructions here http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types/Binding_Types_Reference_Guide#LinkWithAttribute under 'LinkerFlags' and added LinkerFlags = "-liconv". It didn't help, but I'm wondering how this library gets linked without these instructions?

Comment: -liconv is probably not needed, that's why it links fine.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. Out of curiosity, you updated that GitHub repo with that '-unsafe' option added to btouch - Why is that needed now? And did you test it on an actual device afterwards? Does it work for you?

Comment: I added it because I noticed it wouldn't build without it. I didn't test it because I didn't have an actual device handy. I'm pretty sure that the older version (pre 3.2.x) worked. I think it was 3.1.2 or some such.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any pre 3.2.x SDKs. I've tested now with both 3.2.0 build 109 and 3.2.4 build 139. Same issue with both.